# Is it right to share screenshot from MDN documentation?

Tags: support, answers, images, copyright, content

While answering it would be better to share browser compatibility details taken from MDN documentation. Is it OK to take a screenshot from MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) and share somewhere else, e.g., in a Stack Overflow answer?

Comment: Not sure what you ask. Those things are meant to be shared, though better as text quote, not a screenshot.

Comment: @ShadowWizard :  there is a browser compatibility table in their documentation , can I take screenshot and share them?  check here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Browser_compatibility

Comment: As far as I can tell yes, as long as you include a link to that page. (e.g. "taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Browser_compatibility): [screenshot]"

Comment: @ShadowWizard : thanks for the information :)

Comment: Related: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/273494)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fine to quote excerpts from them, but make sure you follow our attribution guidelines.  See the [Help Center's page on how to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Also, if your entire answer consists solely of a quote/excerpt/image from an external source, something is wrong.  We don't want that kind of answer.  Your answer should be your own.  You can use external sources to supplement or support your answer, but we don't want to be just a link farm or an image farm.

It's better to transcribe the contents of the page to text, rather than using an image.  First, that will make the page findable by search.  Second, images aren't accessible to folks with visual impairments (and this is going to happen to many of us as we get older) and sometimes don't display as well on mobile platforms.  So, transcribe to text.

Answer (score 6):

The MDN content are basically meant to be shared. It's fine to share and quote them, but make sure you add a link back. Note that some of the older code snippets are shareable under the MIT license and require a slightly different attribution - the full details are available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/About#Copyrights_and_licenses).

Also note that while sharing a screenshot is generally OK, just copying and/or quoting the relevant context in a textual medium is much easier to work with, and would probably be much more useful to anyone reading your answer.

Comment: @PranavCBalan If you need to paste it as a table (like the example you mentioned), I suggest using [this ASCII table generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/), and pasting it as a code block.